# Can I use HDInsight to create a Spark cluster with a Student subscription?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

That's my question. I have tried googling but couldn't find clues in the  Microsoft documentation. I have my $100 unused, but when I go to HDInsight and try to select the machines type, I cannot select any of them. I always get 0 cores available in every region. I have already enabled Microsoft.Compute as well as Microsoft.HDInsight in my subscription's Resource providers. Should I enable any others?

If it is just not possible at all with a Student subscription, should not it complain from the very beginning (first tab of the process), when I select the subscription for the project in "Project details"?

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, you cannot create the Azure HDInsight cluster with the Student subscription.

**Reason:** With an Azure Student subscription, you will initially be able to access only Azure services that are available with a free tier of service use.

For more limitations, refer to the below links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students/

You may want to look at a [pay-as-you-go subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/) as this should allow you to deploy a cluster, however, may not allow you to utilize the benefits of a student subscription.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0023p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.